# How to make On Item Selected not automatically choose the first entry

Tags: java, android, eclipse, spinner

I have created a spinner which is automatically updated with appliance names when a person adds an appliance using an array adapter. I created an OnItemSelected method with the spinner so when one of the names in the spinner is selected, a new window appears. However the OnItemSelected is automatically selecting the first item on the list when the activity starts and so the user does not have a chance to actually make a selection until the new window appears.

Here is the code:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    startActivity(new Intent("com.lukeorpin.theappliancekeeper.APPLIANCESELECTED"));
    }

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

Does anyone know a way in which the first item on the list wont be automatically selected?

Here is the code for the rest of the spinner:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> appliancenameadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ApplianceNames); //Sets up an array adapter containing the values of the ApplianceNames string array
    applianceName = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_name); //Gives the spinner in the xml layout a variable name
    applianceName.setAdapter(appliancenameadapter); //Adds the contents of the array adapter into the spinner

    applianceName.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Comment: Are you calling setSelection on the Spinner? What's the rest of your Activity code look like?

Comment: I've added the code into the main question, thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to keep onItemSelected from firing off on a newly instantiated Spinner?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562248/how-to-keep-onitemselected-from-firing-off-on-a-newly-instantiated-spinner)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Does anyone know a way in which the first item on the list wont be automatically selected?

There is *always* a selection on `Spinner`, and you cannot change that.

IMHO, you should not be using a `Spinner` to trigger starting an activity.

That being said, you can use a `boolean` to track whether this is the first selection event, and ignore it if it is.

Comment: How would I go about creating a boolean flag for this? I'm very new to java, thanks

Comment: Add a `boolean isFirstSelection=true;` data member to your activity. In `onItemSelected()`, if `isFirstSelection==true`, then just flip it to `false`, otherwise call `startActivity()`. Newcomers to Java should spend some time learning Java outside of Android before doing any Android development.

Comment: Thank you for helping, I've managed to solve it using a boolean flag

Comment: @CommonsWare Do you know how to manage this case with `Spinners` used in the rows of a `ListView`? The method `getView()` can be called multiple times for each row, so I guess we can not use the boolean approach in this case... Any ideas? I implemented this using buttons and AlertDialogs with SingleChoice items filled from a Cursor; but this is actually a "hack".

Comment: @Caumons: I would never dream of putting `Spinners` in a `ListView`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I needed this as I am listing "participations" of students to school and for each one the user can select a comment. I did it with buttons and AlertDialogs, as I was not able to manage Spinners in that scenario.

Answer (score 24):

If you are trying to avoid the initial call to your listener's `onItemSelected()` method, another option is to use `post()` to take advantage of the view's message queue.  The first time the spinner checks for your listener it won't be set yet.

```
// Set initial selection
spinner.setSelection(position);

// Post to avoid initial invocation
spinner.post(new Runnable() {
  @Override public void run() {
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Only called when the user changes the selection
      }

      @Override
      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

It worked for me,

`private boolean isSpinnerInitial = true;`

```
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

        if(isSpinnerInitial)
        {
            isSpinnerInitial = false;
        }
        else  {
            // do your work...
        }

    }
```

Comment: with this first position is not selected

Comment: can't you read question... It simply says "How to make On Item Selected not automatically choose the first entry"

So its for all developers who don't want 1st position selected.

Comment: Ya I understand the answer. I have same requirement but onItemSelected   , Item on the position first is not selected, I had to select the 2nd position item and then first position get selected. Hope u now understand what im saying

Answer (score 0):

Declare variable isSpinnerInitial 
 then make Make a Selection as your default selection

spinnertaggeview.setSelection(-1);  does not make selection as -1 or everything unselected as we do in .Net or other language .
So you can ignore thatline.

```
testStringArrayListinside.add("Make a Selection");
ADD this line so that this is selected by default and user never selects it 

testStringArrayList = (ArrayList<String>) ClinqLinX.get("Tag");
                boolean added = false;
             testStringArrayListinside.add("Make a Selection");
                for (String s : testStringArrayList) {
                    if (s != null || s != "") {
                        String[] results = s.split(","); // split on commas

                        for (String string : results) {

                            testStringArrayListinside.add(string);
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            added = true;
                        }
                    }

                }
                if (added == false) {
                    testStringArrayListinside.add("Not tagged details found");
                }

                spinnertaggeview.refreshDrawableState();

            }

            // Adapter: You need three parameters 'the context, id of the layout (it will be where the data is shown),
            // and the array that contains the data
            if (testStringArrayListinside.size() > 0) {
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getContext(),android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, testStringArrayListinside);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                // Here, you set the data in your ListView
                spinnertaggeview.setAdapter(adapter);
                 isSpinnerInitial = true;

                spinnertaggeview.setSelection(-1);
                spinnertaggeview.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                               int arg2, long arg3) {
                        if (isSpinnerInitial){

                            isSpinnerInitial = false;

                            return;}
                        else{
                        TextView tv = (TextView) arg1;
                        String spinner_value = tv.getText().toString();
                        if (spinner_value.length() == 0) {
                            spinner_value = "Nothing";
                        }
                        String strusername = spinner_value;//As you are using Default String Adapter
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), strusername, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(spinnertaggeview.getContext(), Userdetails.class);
                        intent.putExtra("Username", strusername);
                        spinnertaggeview.getContext().startActivity(intent);}

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

fast copi-paste:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    boolean isInit=false;
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (!isInit){isInit=true; return;}
            //CODE HERE!
        }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {}
});
```